# Can't loop and display a simple List of objects in Struts 2

Tags: java, struts2

I have this class **Dog.java** and a `List<Dog>` that is passed to `dogs.jsp` page.

```
public class Dog {
    public String name;
    public String breed;

    public Dog(String name, String breed) {
        this.name = name;
        this.breed = breed;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getBreed() {
        return breed;
    }

    public void setBreed(String breed) {
        this.breed = breed;
    }
}
```

I try to display each dog, but although it **does loop over all dogs** in the list (displays table headers 5 times), it **doesn't display the dogs names and breeds**. Why?

```
<s:iterator value="dogs" status="x">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Breed</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><s:property value="%{#x.name}"></s:property></td>
            <td><s:property value="%{#x.breed}"></s:property></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br/><br/>

</s:iterator>
```

Comment: `status` is for status, not each item in the iteration. You need to either use the `var` property, or just skip it and use `%{name}` etc. since the item of iteration is at the top of the value stack. Note that this information is contained in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
<s:iterator value="dogs" status="x">
    <br/>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Breed</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><s:property value="%{name}"></s:property></td>
            <td><s:property value="%{breed}"></s:property></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</s:iterator>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<s:iterator value="dogs" var="dog">
  ...  <s:property value="#dog.name" />
 </s:iterator>
```